# Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models

Tags: angular, serve, core-js, npm-version

After updating to Angular 7.3.6, I get the following error on ng serve:

[image]

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in
>   '\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models'

Here is my package.json dependecies:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/router": "^7.2.11",
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.13",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.0.0-rc.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.13.7",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^7.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^7.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.12",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~11.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.0.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^6.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.3",
    "tslint": "~5.14.0",
    "typescript": "3.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you clean your node_modules, node cache and try `npm install` from fresh before running `ng serve`?

Comment: yes I did, but the same error keeps on appearing and I don't know what else to do. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You should install `core-js@2.5.x`

Comment: yes it worked! thank you

Comment: Adding it as answer, please accept.

Comment: Did face the same issue! but thanks to @nircraft, it worked for me too.

Comment: In core-js@3 es7 path removed. Use, for example, core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata. Here is the github link [link](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/412)

Comment: As of July 3, 2019, using Angular-CLI 8.0.6 and Angular 8.1.0, the above error will no longer happen on **NEWLY GENERATED** Angular apps because the offending import is no longer generated in /src/polyfills.ts.

For older Angular applications, I suggest generating a temporary Angular app via:
```
ng new aaTemplate --skip-tests --skip-install
```
Compare the newly generated aaTemplate\src\polyfills.ts with your older application's polyfills.ts and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: For projects being upgraded to Angular 8 or later, you can uninstall core.js as a dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892243/is-not-core-js-needed-anymore

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You should install `core-js@2.5.x` that contains this file/module. See [preset-env docs](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-usage).

Also note, however, that this is a very old version with known issues and is unsupported.  From the module itself:

> "core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js."

Please consider using one of the better solutions below.

Comment: `npm install --save core-js@^2.5.0`, worked for me, thanks

Comment: Works for me too !!

Comment: I decreased the version in package.json to "core-js": "^2.5.4", and run yarn, that worked for me.

Comment: Worked !! Thank you

Comment: Confirmed that npm install --save core-js@^2.5.0 worked for me as well

Comment: For Angular 13, finally I succeeded to get 'ng test' working with ==> npm install --save core-js@^3.3

Comment: This might have been OK back in 2019 but seems *very* bad advice now since "core-js@<3.23.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Some versions have web compatibility issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js."

Answer (score 41):

If you'd like to use version 3.0, you can add the a path to your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "paths": {
            "core-js/es7/reflect": [
                "node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Note: You need check the `node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata` relative path and correct it if needed in your project structure.

Comment: Hi I've seen this also on gh erro reports but haven't managed to make it work, just got the same Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' error....does yours works?

Comment: for me works this  : "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": ["../node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["../node_modules/core-js/es/*"]
    },

Comment: Ran `ncu` which updated all my packages to the latest then used the above and it worked for me.

Comment: I had to add "baseUrl": "." to make it works. Thanks mrapi amd Medeni baykal

Answer (score 33):

### For Angular 8 ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13954#issuecomment-485822832)):

> Angular CLI 8.0+ manages the required Angular polyfills directly and projects will not require a direct dependency on core-js (assuming an application does not manually include additional core-js polyfills).

I've resolved by:

- removing `core-js` from my `package.json` dependencies
- removing `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` from my `test.ts`

Comment: For a similar issue this worked, but I needed to remove the references to `core-js/es{6,7}/reflect` from my `polyfills.ts`

Answer (score 30):

The version 3.0 of core-js has some breaking changes:

https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md

You should find a line similar to this in one of your files: `import "core-js/es7/reflect";`

Change it to this: `import "core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata";`

Comment: This worked for me perfectly - error started after upgrading to angular 8 but your solution worked.

Comment: This, among all the answers, was for me (Angular 11) the solution. Thank you, @Joffrey

Answer (score 25):

In my case , i just changed -->

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

to

```
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

and it worked..

Answer (score 6):

Removing the number at the end of `'es'` in the path, like `'core-js/es/reflect'` worked also for me.

For EX: `import 'core-js/es7/reflect';` was changed to `import 'core-js/es/reflect';`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Hi Dieter, the problem is that your are looking for the "reflect" module in a wrong folder.
1- open the "polyfills.ts" in your src folder.  2 - find the line where there is a line like "import 'core-js/es7/reflect';". Here it is 7 for me, it can be something else in your case. 3- Remove the 7 like that: "import 'core-js/es/reflect';" and it should works.

Answer (score 4):

The tsconfig.json solution from [@medeni](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398923/error-cant-resolve-core-js-es7-reflect-in-node-modules-angular-devkit-bui/55543218#55543218) works, but don't copy the path before checking it by yourself. For me it had to be:

```
"paths": {
  "core-js/es7/reflect": ["../node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata"]
}
```

the ../ is because tsconfig.json is extended by src/tsconfig.app.json or src/tsconfig.spec.json, so /src is the working directory.

*note: I am using Angular CLI 8.1.0*

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it by adding this import: `import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';` in my `polyfills.ts` file

```
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';
```

Make sure you have the latest core-js update and everything should work.

Comment: Basically the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55402062/6243352).

Answer (score 4):

**For angular latest version (currently -> 9) ,**

compatible core-js version is **"core-js": "~2.5.0"**.

step 1) Delete Node modules.

step 2) In package.json file, write  "core-js": "~2.5.0" in dependecies object.

step 3) npm install

then It will work perfectly fine

Answer (score 1):

I found possible answer. You have core-js version 3.0, and this version doesn't have separate folders for ES6 and ES7; that's why the application cannot find correct paths.

To resolve this error, you can downgrade the core-js version to 2.5.7. This version produces correct catalogs structure, with separate ES6 and ES7 folders.

To downgrade the version, simply run:

```
npm i -S core-js@2.5.7
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by removing the number at the end of "es" in the path as in response to [Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/573)

Answer (score 0):

**For Angular 7**

From *package.json* remove:

```
"core-js": "3.6.5",
```

because it is part of the Angular package.