# Migration from Angular 6 to Angular 7 cause error - Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect'

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

```
Global Angular CLI: 7.3.8
Node v10.15.3
NPM 6.4.1
macos
```

I'm getting this error on `npm start`

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/jit-polyfills.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in
>   '/Users/XXX/projects/XXX/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models'
>   ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'core-js/es7/reflect' in '/Users/XXX/projects/XXX/src'

Comment: For projects being upgraded to Angular 8 or later, you can uninstall core.js as a dependency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892243/is-not-core-js-needed-anymore

Comment: @JohnGilmer Thank you for your comment. Feel free to add it as an answer. It will be helpful

Comment: Possible dupe: [Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398923/error-cant-resolve-core-js-es7-reflect-in-node-modules-angular-devkit-bui)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve this issue I've added the following paths to compilerOptions in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "core-js/es7/reflect": [
        "node_modules/core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata",
      ],
      "core-js/es6/*": ["node_modules/core-js/es"]
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

After Migrated to new Angular version, 'core-js/es6' or 'core-js/es7' Will not work.

You have to simply replace import 'core-js/es/'

For ex. import 'core-js/es6/symbol' to import 'core-js/es/symbol'

This will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

just remove the number at the end of 'es' in the path, like 'core-js/es/reflect'. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy all from my oldest project `src/polyfills` to the new imported. That's help ;) .

Comment: What are the contents of the respective files?

Answer (score 0):

Getting this error in `"@angular/cli": "~10.1.5"` project:

> Cannot find module 'core-js/es7/reflect' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Solution:

```js
import * as Reflect from 'core-js/es';
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the question asks about Angular 6 to 7, I'm treating it as a canonical for the error. The import that worked for me in Angular 12 was

```js
import 'core-js/proposals/reflect-metadata';
```

in polyfills.ts.

For reference, here's my package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^12.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "12.5.1",
    "core-js": "3.22.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^12.0.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.1.0",
    "@types/core-js": "2.5.5",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jest": "^27.4.5",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^11.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

.angular-cli.json:

```json
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets", "favicon.ico"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": ["styles.css"],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

See also [Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in '\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55398923/error-cant-resolve-core-js-es7-reflect-in-node-modules-angular-devkit-bui)