# Is not core-js needed anymore?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular8

I've updated an Angular project from version 7 to 8. Everything runs smoothly, schematics did it's job (maybe) and we are Ok (project is even in production). When we're updating Angular CLI, we always generate a new project to see the real differences and learn from them such as new dependencies, configurations, etc.

When generating a new Angular project with Angular CLI 8.0.4, the new app doesn't have `core-js` as dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

Analyzing bundle on built project `core-js` is not there:
[image: Bundle without core-js]
On my *older* project, updated with Angular CLI, `core-js` is there and is present in the final bundle:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.3",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "2.1.1",
    "@hackages/ngxerrors": "~8.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "5.0.0-rc.1",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "~4.2.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "~4.2.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "~2.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "~12.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "~4.3.1",
    "core-js": "~2.6.9",
    "d3-scale": "~3.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "~1.3.5",
    "date-fns": "2.0.0-beta.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "~8.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "~10.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "tslib": "~1.10.0",
    "xlsx": "~0.14.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  }
```

[image: core-js present in final bundle]

Why is this behavior? Is it safe to remove `core-js` as dependency? Does update schematics missing this? When installing `npm` dependencies on the newest project I get the post-install messages from `core-js`, but it is not explicitly present in package description.

Comment: Is `core-js` and `core.js` highlighted in above picture same?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

According to [this](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/angular-cli-8.0/) article.

> Note that core-js has been updated to v3, and is now directly handled by the CLI itself, so it’s no longer needed as a dependency of your application.

Comment: @h0b0, it's definitely helpful and nice to know, thanks!

Comment: With older versions of common.js you still needed to add es7 polyfills manually since these were not added by the CI. But with Angular 10.0.4 you no longer need to do this since common.js no longer separates polyfills by language version.

Answer (score 32):

If you look in `src/polyfills.ts` in an Angular 7 or earlier project, you'll see a bunch of comments and commented out import statements that allow you to add polyfills for various browsers by uncommenting them - most come from core.js.

In Angular 8, with the advent of [Differential Loading](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading), the CLI will build 2 bundles - one with and one without polyfills, based on your requirements in the `browserslist` file and your tsconfig file.

> The Angular CLI handles differential loading for you as part of the build process for deployment. The ng build command produces the necessary bundles used for differential loading, based on your browser support requirements and compilation target.

The difference with core-js in ng8 is that, since the CLI is handling polyfills, core-js is a dependency of the CLI. So even if you uninstall core-js as part of upgrading to ng8, you'll see it's still in your node_modules folder, but you won't have to manage which version is installed.

After you've upgraded your project and the CLI to angular 8, I would suggest you do this:

1. replace the contents of polyfills.ts with the contents of the same file in a newly generated ng8 or later project
2. Uninstall core-js from your project.

Now you can build your project and the CLI takes care of the polyfills.

Comment: Yeah, if it only worked... `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'`

Comment: @Endrju polyfills are still added but, as I mentioned in my answer, you need to ensure your browserslist file is set up to include browsers you want to support so they get polyfilled

Comment: Yeah I've double checked that, and am still getting the error in IE11. https://pastebin.com/NiztQV2n

Comment: @Endrju maybe you can post a question so we can get a more complete view of the issue

Comment: this is key:  'replace the contents of polyfills.ts with the contents of the same file in a newly generated ng8 project' worked perfectly - I copied the polyfills.ts file from an Angular 10 Project and it worked like a charm